# Rails Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I am teaching myself rails and I am trying to create simple blog type webpage. However, I keep getting this error message every time I try to run from the command line.

```
rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text created_at:datetime
←[31mCould not find gem 'rails (= 3.2.2) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

I have Ruby v1.9.3 and Rails v. I have also downloaded RubyGems v1.8.17. I have re-installed all three, and made sure they are added to the PATH. I'm guessing its something simple I am missing but I just don't understand what the message is asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did  you generate a new project 1st using

```
rails new project_name
```

If you did, it's telling you to run bundle install. Did you trying typing "bundle install" into the command line?

Comment: Yeh C:\> rails new blog, then I changed directories and tried to run the above command. After I got the message I went to the ruby193 bin directory and tried bundle install but I get could not find gem error

Comment: you changed directories to the project directory, right?
bundle install should also be run from the project directory, not the ruby bin directory

Comment: Ah ok thats what was wrong. I was using bundle install in the bin directory. Thank you.

Comment: You also should probably not be creating your project directory under `C:\`, but in your home directory.